# string concatenation in a loop happens to be on the left . Why?

Tags: python

String concatenation happens to be on the right side, example:

```
foo = 'Sorting1234'
foo += 'er'
print(foo)

Sorting1234er
```

But in a loop this happens:

```
string = 'Sorting1234'
x = ''
for c in string:
    if c.islower():
        x+=c
    if c.isupper():
        x+=c
print(x)

Sorting
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
ortingS
```

Since I am 'appending' the lowercase first in the loop and 'appending' the uppercase later.

Comment: Actually, you are processing the letters in the order of the original string, rather than by case.

Comment: You're appending the letters in the order they come from the string. The `if` statements test mutually exclusive conditions, so only one can be run on each iteration of the loop anyway; the order of those `if` statements does not matter.

Comment: To get your expected output, you'd need two loops: in the first one append to the string only if `.islower()`, and in the second one append only if `.isupper()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you are processing the letters in the order of the original string, rather than by case. This means that your current `for` loop has little effect but to prevent the printing of numeric values.

One way to achieve the behaviour you're looking for, with the lower case characters appended first, would be to use two loops: the first looking for lower case characters and the second looking for upper case characters, i.e.:

```
string = 'Sorting1234'
x = ''
for c in string:
    if c.islower():
        x += c
for c in string:
    if c.isupper():
        x += c
print(x)
```

Output:

```
ortingS
```

An alternative way, requiring one pass over the string, could be to store lists of the lower and upper case characters, then join them at the end:

```
lower, upper = [], []                                                           
for c in string:                                                                
    if c.islower():                                                             
        lower.append(c)                                                         
    elif c.isupper():                                                           
        upper.append(c)                                                         
print(''.join(lower + upper))
```

Output:

```
ortingS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'Sorting1234'
x = ''
for c in string:
    if c.islower():
        x+=c
    if c.isupper():
        x+=c
    print(x)
print(x)
x=''
#x += c -> x = x + x -> appends c to the right of x, which it's doing it correctly
```

When printing the output you can see:

```
S                                                                                                                 
So                                                                                                                
Sor                                                                                                               
Sort                                                                                                              
Sorti                                                                                                             
Sortin                                                                                                            
Sorting
```

You can see you are simply looping through the string and appending each letter, the if statements are practically useless in your case.